# Unable to update a testrun state to completed via API

Tags: api, testing, curl, azure-devops

We have been using curl with the VSTS / Azure API v5.1 to create testruns, post test results and set testruns with a state of 'completed' for a good while.

For the past few weeks, our requests to patch the testrun state to 'completed' from 'inProgress' are not committed.

(Yet we can use the same request to update other testrun attributes like the value for 'comment')

Documentation still mentions acceptable values to supply for state:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#updating-started-date

Are you able to complete your testruns via the API?  Thanks

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic {token}" --request PATCH -d "{'state':'Completed','build':{'id': 0},'comment':'an updated comment'}" https://dev.azure.com/etc/etc/_apis/test/runs/{testrunID}?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: I also can't update to Completed (still can update to other states and other attributes).

Comment: @David Hi,David Do you try the curl command in powershell task? Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I can confirm that our curl command run in CMD is now successfully setting the testrun state to 'completed'. As mentioned earlier, it was able to change other aspects of the testrun record, (eg comment) but for the last few weeks did not affect the state. Now the state is updating too. This would suggest to me the issue probably wasn't our side, as our curl api request hasn't changed. Glad to see it's resolved though.

Answer (score 0):

I can update the state to `Completed`successfully via REST API:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organizaion}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runid}?api-version=5.1

Request Body:
{
  "state": "Completed"
}
```

But it only updated the test run state, if the result is not `Passed`, then there will be a triangular exclamation mark near the Completed state. 
So, to completely update the state we have to update the test result `outcome` to `Passed` :

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runid}/Results?api-version=5.1

Request body:
[
  {
    "id": 100000,
    "outcome": "Passed"
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for your reply. However, I am seeing different behaviour.

1. Post new testrun
2. Post a pass testresult   (1 test showing as passed in testruns for the current run)
3. Attempt to set the testrun state as 'Completed' -- this does not update the testrun state. I am left with a testrun in 'Waiting' state, containing one passed testcase.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I test with the following script in the PowerShell task of azure devops and can successfully modify the any state of the testrun to Completed .

```
$connectionToken="your token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

curl.exe  -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic $base64AuthInfo" --request PATCH -d "{'state':'Completed','comment':'an updated comment'}" https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=5.1
```